# Xcode beginner. New file problems and error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I'm new to Xcode and am having problems. I'll go through my steps and describe my problem. So, I want to code in C++... I

1. Open Xcode
2. New Project... Command line tool
3. Add the project to my designated programming folder
4. Run the Hello World program given and everything works well.

The problem is when I try to add a new file to my current project. I click file -> new file -> C++ class. So lets say I name this file practice.cpp, when I do this it also creates practice.h with all the headers. I however, would prefer all my code with headers in one window as my programs are minimal for now. Also, if I do try to create a simple program, say copied from the Hello World that previously worked or anything else I get an error. "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
I've scoured the internet and have not found a fix. Thank you all!

Edit: Sorry about that, I think maybe there's a duplicate but I'm not sure how to go about understanding or fixing the error. Anyway, here's the error...

Ld /Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Products/Debug/CSE1222 normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/Finn/Desktop/School/CSE 1222/CSE1222/CSE1222"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Intermediates/CSE1222.build/Debug/CSE1222.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CSE1222.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Intermediates/CSE1222.build/Debug/CSE1222.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CSE1222_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Products/Debug/CSE1222

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Intermediates/CSE1222.build/Debug/CSE1222.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Intermediates/CSE1222.build/Debug/CSE1222.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/File1.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Is there any sort of indication as to a specific linker error?

Comment: show us description of the linker error.

Comment: I edited the original post and included the error. Like I said it says there's a duplicate in _main. So would I just not include the int main() in the second program or would I have to save it somewhere else and not in the same folder. Also, the .h file included with practice.cpp, how do i get rid of it and just use practice.cpp? Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So lets say I name this file practice.cpp, when I do this it also
>   creates practice.h with all the headers. I however, would prefer all
>   my code with headers in one window as my programs are minimal for now.

No problem -- you can put everything in one file if you want, and just delete the header file. You should realize, however, that putting class declarations etc. in separate header files is a standard practice, even for relatively small programs. It might be better to get used to using separate header files because you're going to have to learn to work that way eventually anyway.

> duplicate symbol _main in:
>   /Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Intermediates/CSE1222.build/Debug/CSE1222.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
>   /Users/Finn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSE1222-caatcfzekizvqkcdenxbphbfseon/Build/Intermediates/CSE1222.build/Debug/CSE1222.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/File1.o

You've got a duplicate symbol, specifically `_main`. That is, `_main` is defined in two different object files that are built from your project: `main.o` and `File1.o`. This probably means that you tried to build your whole program in a file called `File1.cpp`, and that you ignored the `main.m` file that Xcode supplies in the new project. You could try removing `main.m`; or remove `File1.cpp`, rename `main.m` to `main.cpp`, and put all your code in there.

Answer (score 0):

I just untick the target membership in one .cpp file and the other one can be built.